# How to disable the spin buttons for input number?

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to add an element of input type number using createElement() in Vue with typescript.
Is there a way to disable the spin buttons for increment and decrement?
I have already tried using :

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer.spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

But after the build and deploying, I am not able to see the changes.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that you have a typo in your CSS. `-webkit-outer.spin-button` should be `-webkit-outer-spin-button`. The full thing is:

```css
input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

FYI, for my use case I just discovered [here](https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/) a much better option than this hack to hide the buttons, which might work for you too:

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked until recently.
I added `display: none;` to the CSS Selector.
So it is now:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer.spin-button {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note there is a typo in the CSS here. `-webkit-outer.spin-button` should be `-webkit-outer-spin-button`